# UIWebview JavaScriptCore framework test for undefined object in Javascript context

Tags: ios, objective-c, javascriptcore

I'm using the JavaScriptCore in UIWebview with help from [this](http://blog.impathic.com/post/64171814244/true-javascript-uiwebview-integration-in-ios7) and the WWDC 2013 Integrating JavaScript into Native Apps video.

In Objective-C I want to test if some object in the Javascript context is `undefined`. This is what I do:

```
//self.ctx previously from [self.webview valueForKeyPath:@"documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext"];
if (self.ctx[@"Web2App"] == [JSValue valueWithUndefinedInContext:self.ctx]) {
    // Do something
}
```

However, it appears to work in simulator, but not in real device (iOS 7).

How do I test if an object is defined in the Javascript context?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!JSValueIsUndefined(self.ctx, self.ctx[@"Web2App"])) {
 // Do someting                 
}
```

I found that in the [javascript core](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/JavaScriptCore/Reference/JSValueRef_header_reference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011501) docs